# php foreach as key, every two number as a group

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php
$data=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11');
foreach($data as $key=> $element){
    if($key % 2 != 0){
        echo $element.'<br />';
    }
    echo '<hr />';
}
?>
```

php foreach as key, how to make every two number as a group?

I want to output:

```
1,2
_____
3,4
_____
5,6
_____
7,8
_____
9,10
_____
11
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look at the [`array_chunk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function.

In your case you'd use it like this:

```
foreach(array_chunk($data, 2) as $values) {
    echo implode(',', $values)."\n";
}
```

During the last iteration `$values` will have only one element so if you plan to access the elements directly using their index remember to use `count()` to check the array's element count.

Answer (score 7):

Your foreach() is fine but you want to print every element, not just every even one. You also don't want the horizontal rule every time either, just every even. Thus:

```
<?php
$data=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11');
foreach($data as $key=> $element){
    echo $element;
    if($key % 2 != 0){
        echo "<br/><hr />";
    }
    else {
        echo ",";
    }
}
?>
```