# Can I use XPath or something else like a regex to extract data from XML?

Tags: php, regex, xml, xpath

Certainly I could use regular expressions to parse data from an XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions>
  <message name="notificationInput">
    <part name="body" element="xsd:notificationRequest" />
  </message>
  <message name="notificationOutput">
    <part name="body" element="xsd:notificationResponse" />
  </message>
</definitions>
```

A pattern like

```
/<message.*name="(.*)".*part.*name=".*".*element="xsd:(.*)".*<\/message>/sUg
```

would probably give me the data I want, here shown as a PHP array:

```
array(
  array("notificationInput", "body", "notificationRequest"),
  array("notificationOutput", "body", "notificationResponse")
)
```

This is of course extremely cumbersome and error-prone.

I know how to use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) to query complete nodes, but I don't think I can tell it *"I want attributes `name` and `element` from node `/definitions/message/part` and for each result I also want attribute `name` from its parent"*.

Now I wonder if there is some language or technique (prefereably with an implementation in PHP) that I can use to specify the data I want to extract.

In other words, I am looking for a solution that more or less can be configured instead of programmed, because I have quite a few similar definitions to extract.

Comment: So the `array(...)` part is the expected result, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sure... (stupid minimum comment length)

Comment: Is there exactly one `<part>` node per `<message>` or possibly >1?

Comment: In reality there can be more than one, but that would be a problem I would have to work around with regex as well, so you may choose to ignore it in your answer. :)

Comment: Are you already using DOMDocument (from which DOMXpath comes) elsewhere in your project? This would be quite easily done with a single loop (or one nesting) with SimpleXML.

Comment: DOMDocument was a rather arbitrary choice, I could switch to SimpleXML or XMLReader. However, I already did it with a loop and a function call, but I have a lot of other similar definitions to extract, so I was looking for a solution that can be configured instead of programmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This short XPath 1.0 expression selects all wanted attribute nodes**:

```
/*//*/@*
```

Then for each selected node you can get its string value using PHP (which I don't know).

---

**If you can use XPath 2.0, then all wanted values are produced by evaluating a similar expression**:

```
/*//*/@*/data(.)
```

**Here is a simple XSLT 2.0 transformation that just evaluates the above expression and outputs the result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="/*//*/@*/data(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<definitions>
  <message name="notificationInput">
    <part name="body" element="xsd:notificationRequest" />
  </message>
  <message name="notificationOutput">
    <part name="body" element="xsd:notificationResponse" />
  </message>
</definitions>
```

**The wanted result is produced**:

```
notificationInput body xsd:notificationRequest notificationOutput body xsd:notificationResponse
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the XPath

```
//message/@name|//message[@name]/part/@name|//message/part/@element
```

to generate a 1-dimensional sequence of all the desired attributes (sorry, this is in Python):

```
In [366]: doc.xpath('//message/@name|//message[@name]/part/@name|//message/part/@element')
Out[366]: 
['notificationInput',
 'body',
 'xsd:notificationRequest',
 'notificationOutput',
 'body',
 'xsd:notificationResponse']
```

and then use [`array_chunk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6852550/190597) to rearrange the result in groups of 3. (Note you would still need to use a bit of regex or string manipulation to remove the `xsd:` from the `notificationResponse`, but that would still be much easier and more robust than using regex to parse the XML.

The XPath will collect all the attributes even if there is more than one `<part>` per `<message>`.

Comment: This works only if there is exactly one `<part>` in each `<message>`, though.

Comment: `concat(//message/@name,' | ', //message/part/@name,' | ', substring-after( //message/part/@element, 'xsd:'))` returns fine result `notificationInput | body | notificationRequest`. But i wonder why just the first match?

Answer (score 0):

I know that parsing html with regex is not recommended, unless you know what is the character set involved, but I post this answer since it might be useful for you.

For the sample text you provided, you can use a simple regex like this:

```
([a-z]+)"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tI2mU1/1)**

**Php** code:

```
$re = "/([a-z]+)\"/i"; 
$str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<definitions>\n  <message name=\"notificationInput\">\n    <part name=\"body\" element=\"xsd:notificationRequest\" />\n  </message>\n  <message name=\"notificationOutput\">\n    <part name=\"body\" element=\"xsd:notificationResponse\" />\n  </message>\n</definitions>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Then you can grab the captured content from `$matches`.

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [53-70] `notificationInput`
MATCH 2
1.  [89-93] `body`
MATCH 3
1.  [108-127]   `notificationRequest`
MATCH 4
1.  [162-180]   `notificationOutput`
MATCH 5
1.  [199-203]   `body`
MATCH 6
1.  [218-238]   `notificationResponse`
```