# Show the two elements in foreach loop in every iteration?

Tags: php, foreach

How we can show the two elements in for each loop in each iteration?

For example I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f');
```

And want to show the records like this:

```
  a-b
  c-d
  e-f
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852550/php-foreach-as-key-every-two-number-as-a-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852550/php-foreach-as-key-every-two-number-as-a-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the array with `for`.

Print the current and current plus one value in each iteration by counter.

Increment the counter.

```
<?php
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f');
$i=0;
$len = count($arr);
for ($i=0; $i< $len; $i++) { // We could have used count($arr) 
//instead of $len. But, it will lead to 
//multiple calls to count() function causing code run slowly.
    echo "<br/>".$arr[$i] . '-' . $arr[$i+1];
  ++$i; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Hmm, with this solution you'll have an `Undefined offset: <faulty_offset_number>` if `$len%2 = 1`

Comment: This also has index increment operations (`$i++`) in multiple places, which might be confusing. Better to increment `$i` by two each time, e.g. `for ($i=0; $i< $len; $i += 2)`. Though an undefined offset error is still an issue.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `array_chunk`, it is meant exactly for these kind of cases and it's the shortest and most efficient way to do it.

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f');
foreach(array_chunk($arr , 2) as $val) {
    echo implode('-', $val)."\n";
}
```

> Chunks an array into arrays with size elements.

More details:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Demo: https://3v4l.org/BGNbq

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f');
  $length = count($array);
  for ($i=0; $i< $length; $i+2) {
      echo "<br/>".$arr[$i] . '-' . $arr[$i+1]; 
  }
?>
```